# How to render multiple component in reactjs, what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs

First i have a function to fetch data from database then

if the data be changed, i will create list components.

but it didnt work, what i'm doing wrong?

console:

```
class TweetContainer extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tweetData:{}, 
            tweetRender : [],
            listTweet:[]
        }
    }
```

here is my function to fetch data from database

```
    componentDidMount(){
        
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/tweet')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(result=>{
            this.setState({
                tweetData: result
            }, ()=>console.log(this.state.tweetData));
        });
        
    }
```

my function to make list component

```
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.state.tweetRender = this.state.tweetData.data.slice(1,6);
        console.log(this.state.tweetRender);
        
        this.state.listTweet = this.state.tweetRender.map((tweet)=><Tweet 
        linkAvatar={'/image/jennyshen.jpg'}
        name={"Vuongxuan"}
        userName={'@vuggg'}
        tweetText={tweet.content} />);

        console.log(this.state.listTweet);

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div id="main">
                <h2>Tweet</h2>
                <div id="stream">
                   {this.state.listTweet}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

i dont know what i'm doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to React docs, componentDidMount lifecycle most common use is for:

> Updating the DOM in response to prop or state changes.

And you want to get and render the tweets, right? Not necessarily listen to updates.

For now a solution is remove your `componentDidUpdate()` method and change your `render´ method to:

```
render(){
    var tweetRender = this.state.tweetData.data.slice(1,6);
    return(
        <div id="main">
            <h2>Tweet</h2>
            <div id="stream">
                {listTweet.map((tweet, idx) => 
                    <Tweet
                        key={idx}
                        linkAvatar={'/image/jennyshen.jpg'}
                        name={"Vuongxuan"}
                        userName={'@vuggg'}
                        tweetText={tweet.content} />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: no, i'm using component did mount to fetch data from database. i'm trying your solution, but it didn't work: https://i.imgur.com/2OXzKU4.png

Comment: where can we chat?

Comment: pls contact my via facebook: https://twitter.com/vuongvuonghehe?lang=vi

Comment: Cant find you in facebook, do you have skype?

Comment: THANK A LOT, YOU'RE AWESOME.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not a good idea to put React elements (JSX) inside your component state. You could instead just store the data in state, and derive the JSX from that data in the render method.

**Example**

```js
class TweetContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tweetData: [],
    tweetRender: [],
    listTweet: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        tweetData: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "foo",
            username: "@foo"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "bar",
            username: "@bar"
          }
        ]
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="main">
        <h2>Tweet</h2>
        <div id="stream">
          {this.state.tweetData.map(obj => (
            <div key={obj.id}>
              {obj.username} - {obj.name}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TweetContainer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```